# How can I get the first 8 characters of a string on VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how i can put in a variable the first 8 (or whatever the number) characters of a string in a range on Excel macro.

I have this code but I don't find how to get a certain number of characters on those ranges.

```
sourceBook.Sheets(1).Name = sourceBook.Sheets(1).Range("first_name") & " - " & sourceBook.Sheets(1).Range("last_name")
```

Comment: Check [Left function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Left function e.g.

```
Public Function func(s As String, n As Integer) As String
    'returns the first n characters of a string
    func = Left$(s, n)
End Function
```